# Kotlin - retrieve data from HashMap of Key Value pairs

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, hashmap

[image]

How do I retrieve the price (649) from this?

Currently I have this but I want to reach the value directly

```
for (product in snapshot.value) {

                    if (product.key.equals("price")) {
                        price = Integer.parseInt(product.value as String)
                    }
 }
```

Comment: What's the type of `snapshot` here? You show the value of `snapshot.value`, but you're using `snapshot.children`. How does `snapshot.value` relate to `snapshot.children`?

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying snapshot.children. I have corrected the code now.

Comment: snapshot is Datasnapshot

Comment: Unrelated, but it looks like the value you get should actually be converted to an object rather than into a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So its this

```
 var dataMap = snapshot.value as MutableMap<Any, Any>

 var priceKV = dataMap["price"]
 price = Integer.parseInt(priceKV.toString())
```

Comment: Casting with generic types is usually unsafe. In this specific case, it's not really unsafe because you're using `Any`, but in that case you can't access the values from the map with the proper types without casting again (the type of `priceKV` here will be `Any`). Also, I believe `value` is nullable in Firebase's API, so we should account for it in the cast. That said, I believe it's better to use the typed versions of `getValue` (especially the ones from `firebase-database-ktx`). Also, why keep a `MutableMap` if you don't intend to change it?

Answer (score 3):

If `snapshot.value` is a `HashMap<String, String>` (which it seems to be), you can do the following:

```kotlin
val price = snapshot.value["price"].toInt()
```

EDIT: since your `snapshot` variable is a `DataSnapshot` from Firebase, `snapshot.value` is declared of type `Any` (Java's `Object`) as far as I can tell from [the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getValue()). This means you can't use it as a `Map` directly, you first have to make the compiler understand its type via a cast, or use a specifically typed method to access it.

You can access the value in the proper type using `getValue(GenericTypeIndicator)`:

```kotlin
val map = snapshot.getValue(object : GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, String>>() {})
    ?: error("map missing in firebase snapshot")
```

Or even better if you use the `firebase-database-ktx` dependency:

```kotlin
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.getValue

val map = snapshot.getValue<Map<String, String>>()
    ?: error("map missing in firebase snapshot")
```

You can then access your price from the map via one of the following ways (depending on whether you accept missing "price" keys or not):

```kotlin
val price = map["price"]?.toInt() // if you accept nulls for the price

val price = map.getValue("price").toInt() // if you want to fail on missing price
```

Last but not least, I'm not an expert in Firebase API, but I really believe you should be using a proper class with properties instead of a `Map` to deserialize this payload. Something like:

```kotlin
data class Product(
    val amount: Int,
    val datetime: String,
    val quantity: Int,
    val productID: String,
    val price: Int,
    val imageUrl: String,
    val discount: Discount?, // not sure what is supposed to be here
    val productName: String,
)
```

Comment: @whoadityanawandar I updated my answer based on the additional info

Comment: I do have the class and it is being used when I retrieve the data with FirebaseRecyclerOptions. This, what I have done, is for getting the data (to work on) before sending it to the adapter. I am doing this in the addChangeEventListener.